# Meteor: event.target.value is undefined on mouseenter/mouseleave event

Tags: javascript, meteor, styles, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have, in my Meteor app, a table representing a week, and each td element have the following structure:

```
<td id="day_hour" style="style" class="class" value="0,4 or 10">text</td>
```

An example of td element would be:

```
<td id="lundi_{{id_heure}}" class="semaine" value={{valeurLundi}} style="background-color:hsla({{valeurLundi}}9, 75%, 55%, 1); border: white solid 5px; text-align:center; color:white;font-weight: bold; cursor:pointer;">
    {{#if lundiIsOk}} ✓ {{else}} {{#if lundiMaybe}} ~ {{else}} ✕ {{/if}} {{/if}}
</td>
```

This element represents the first hour of Monday and the value is used to determine the background-color of the element. In that particular case in the app, the value is set to 0 and the background-color of the td is set accordingly.

To guide the user and show him interaction is possible with those td elements, I want to slightly modify the background-color property when he hovers on them. While trying to get it to work, I realized that, apparently, using css like so:

```
.semaine:hover{
    background-color:hsla({{valeurLundi}}9,55%,55%,1);
}
```

doesn't work. I guess it's because of the fact it need values from a helper and that even if my style tag is inside the template, css doesn't like that and thus won't work. Trying to use a conventional color like lightgreen or black didn't work either, so I decided to use events for the template.

Playing with the mouseenter and mouseleave events, I ended up with the following code (note: I used black in the mouseenter event to test with a drastic color change):

```
'mouseenter .semaine': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(event.target).css({"background-color":"black"});
},
'mouseleave .semaine': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(parseInt(event.currentTarget.value) == 0){
        $(event.target).css({"background-color":"hsl(9, 75%, 55%, 1)"});
    }
    else if(parseInt(event.currentTarget.value) == 4){
        $(event.target).css({"background-color":"hsl(49, 75%, 55%, 1)"});
    }
    else if(parseInt(event.currentTarget.value) == 10){
        $(event.target).css({"background-color":"hsl(109, 75%, 55%, 1)"});
    }
}
```

As you can see, the background-color is supposed to revert back what it used to be once the user leaves the td element. My problem is here: event.currentTarget.value returns undefined.

Because I first thought I was maybe due to the event.currentTarget not being defined from the beginning, I played with console logs and discovered that not only event.currentTarget does return the correct td element, but I can also return the id, the style and the class, even the innerHTML of the element, but not its value, which is the only attribute that is returned as undefined.

Needless to day I'm really confused, especially since I also use event.currentTarget.value on other events such as a click, and it works there. I must add that I also tried to use the jQuery $(event.target).val(), which also returns undefined.

Any idea why it behaves this way?

Comment: Are you sure `event.currentTarget` is `td` not some root element handler was attached to? Also td elements have no value property you could try using data-attribute instead. For example `data-value="blah"`.

Comment: It is the td element, I tried using a console log. It's strange, because the value attributes seems to function elsewhere. I'll try the data-value. How would then get a data-value in the event?

Comment: `event.target.dataset.value` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: Seems to work, thanks!